# Creating PowerShell if statement for True over time

Tags: powershell, csv, logic

I have CSV document. Each row of the CSV has a timestamp, along with various performance metrics as they were when recorded at that time.

What I want to be able to do is consume the csv and perform a logic test on it of this kind of nature:

If said metric is above a specified threshold for a specified amount of time = True

I can easily setup a logic statement comparing two numbers/metrics, but I wasn't sure how to add in the component as to whether that condition is true for a certain amount of time.

CSV might look something like this:

```
time,KB/sec,IOPS,Avg. Latency ms
8/6/2017 10:30,10616.79606,117.2243058,35.63250298
8/6/2017 10:20,11337.82872,149.4084982,28.55670254
8/6/2017 10:17,12276.47016,172.2729097,25.43457276
8/6/2017 10:14,10125.01863,106.2432985,37.38492431
8/6/2017 10:11,12185.1857,127.452136,32.40784617
```

So I might want to know if the latency is consistently over a certain amount for a couple of hours for instance

I could use a bit of direction and would greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: When you say a certain amount of time, are you wanting to specify hours or are you wanting to target days. Will need to know your inputs for what you'll be commonly polling the csv data for.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the values from your CSV from string to the proper type (`DateTime` and `double` respectively).

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $_.time     = [DateTime]$_.time
    $_.'KB/sec' = [double]$_.'KB/sec'
    $_.IOPS     = [double]$_.IOPS
    ...
}
```

Check if the value in question is above the given threshold. You have 3 cases to cover:

- *The value exceeds the threshold for the first time:* remember the current timestamp.
- *The value exceeds the threshold and also exceeded it in the previous iteration:* calculate the difference between the current timestamp and the previously remembered timestamp. Return `$true` if the timespan is greater than the maximum duration you want to accept.
- *The value does not exceed the threshold:* forget the previously remembered timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Well not knowing exactly what you're aiming for perhaps the below will help.

```
function Monitor-Something
{
    Param
    (

        $Date = '8/6/2017',

        $StartTime = '10:17',

        $StopTime = '10:30',

        $Threshold,

        $CSVLogfile = 'C:\temp\test.csv'
    )

    Begin
    {

    }
    Process
    {
        $csv = Import-Csv $CSVLogfile

        [datetime]$monitorStart = $("$Date $StartTime")
        [datetime]$monitorStop = $("$Date $StopTime")

        foreach($item in $csv)
        {
            [datetime]$objDateTime = $item.time
            if($objDateTime -gt $monitorStart -and $objDateTime -lt $monitorStop)
            {
                #do stuff here, compare against your threshold report things build an object for an output
                $item.IOPS #This is here just to show you a successful result
            }

        }

    }
    End
    {
        #return some report or object that you can analyze
    }
}
```